# The component cannot be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x88982F50) UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I got this error when trying to pick a folder then displaying all the images in it.
my code:

```
 var folderPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker();
            folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
            var folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
            var filesList = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
            for (int i = 0; i < filesList.Count ; i++)
            {
                using (var stream = await filesList[i].OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
                {
                    var bitmapImage = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
                    await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(stream);
                    Image m = new Image();
                    m.Source = bitmapImage;
                    sp1.Children.Add(m);
                }

            }
```

it does work when the folder has 4 or 5 images, but more than that i get this error. any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably not in the number of images you are displaying, but in the fact, that you are trying to display a file that is not an image.

In the top of your code you are applying a filter to only ".jpg" images, but this filter applies only to what is displayed in the folder picker dialog, not to what the `GetFilesAsync` method returns. This means your `filesList` contains all the files in the folder not only images. To fix this, you can create a filter using the `CreateFileQueryWithOptions` method first:

```
 var filesList =
    await folder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(
          new QueryOptions( CommonFileQuery.DefaultQuery,
                            new string[] {".jpg"} )
       ).GetFilesAsync();
```

You can try see my sample app with this solution [on my GitHub](https://github.com/MartinZikmund/Stack-Overflow-2016/tree/master/ImageFolderDisplay).

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks <3